# Is it possible to make CSS3 columns on a horizontal plane?

Tags: css, multiple-columns

I would like to know if it is possible to produce CSS3 columns horizontally.

for ex. if I have paragraphs a, b, c, and d and I give them "column-count: 2" the output would be

a c

b d

I would like to create the column so that the output would become

a b

c d

Does anyone know if this is possible while using css3 columns?

I'd prefer my page to be scalable and that's why I'd rather use columns so that the column-count would automatically produce the right amount of columns compared to the screen size.

The original page uses mostly 3-4 columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Giving the paragraphs a width and floating left should work if you specify a min/max width to the paragraphs. It should work with a variable width wrapper element but may break if you don't allow the paragraphs to scale much with restricted widths.

```
p {
    float: left;
    max-width: 160px;
    min-width: 100px;
    margin: 20px;
}

div { //wrapper
    width: 480px;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kj8JU/)

Don't forget to clear the float in the element after the columns.

Comment: I'll give that a try.. it's a shame if you can't control the alignment for the filling of a column.. would be really usefull

Comment: Worked great, thanks! Sorting is as wanted, just have to align it again.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked for you. :D Any chance you can accept the answer?

Comment: Aah.. sorry, used this two times so far and didn't notice the accept sign.. I'll accept it right away!

Comment: Hmm, doesn't actually work as well as I thought it did. It seems the columns just take up the max-width unless the container gets smaller than that. I thought it would resize the elements to the min-width if there was room for two next to each other.

Comment: Yes, but in case you have elements with fixed width like images or a li group as I do, then it works as wanted.. as in it presents as many items as possible for that width..

But the the idea behind your solution is interesting.. I think it could be possible to arrange it using for example stylus, where you can insert functions or math a lot better within CSS.