# Two column horizontal flow with CSS

Tags: html, css, layout, multiple-columns

I want to achieve a flow of DIVs similar to this:

[image]

Where divs flow left to right and top to bottom.

If I try floats, 3 starts at the height where 2 ends... So I'm wondering... Is there a way of doing this with CSS?

Edit: As I'm getting the divs from a database using PHP, I can't just move the 2 to the 3 or something like that.

Edit: Heights and number of divs are also variable.

Comment: Can you use absolute position?

Comment: No, because the heights are variable.

Just added a clarifcation, thanks!

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14649919/is-it-possible-to-make-css3-columns-on-a-horizontal-plane

Answer (score 2):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/auhgk0jq/

use `column` and set `inline-block` for the divs inside parent so that it doesn't left the part

below is the rough example

```css
.cont {
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  /* Firefox */
  column-count: 2;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-gap: 10px;
  /* Firefox */
  column-gap: 10px;
}
.cont div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 4px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background: cornflowerblue;
}
.cont .two,
.cont .six {
  height: 90px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="one">1</div>
  <div class="two">2</div>
  <div class="three">3</div>
  <div class="four">4</div>
  <div class="five">5</div>
  <div class="six">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: He said `divs flow left to right and top to bottom.` How can this be solution in that case?

Comment: he also mentioned this in his comment _If I try to use columns 2 goes to 3 and 3 starts below 2 and gets cut_ @AdityaPonkshe

Comment: I mentioned that because I was going to do that as an alternative (which I'll gladly use if there's no way to do what I want), will remove that part. Sorry, it's kind of late and I've been stressed with this for long time.

Comment: @Vitorino Fernandes  he want block 2 right from block 1, your effect is underneath

Comment: After implementing this, I'm getting white space after (in this example) the "cont" div, but only in certain cases (where there are more than 2 items) and only in Chrome. Opera doesn't show the white space, but only does columns once, then ignores the rest. Firefox works okay... so I guess I'm not using this either until this gets a little more standard.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be achieved by using `relative` positions. You need to give `absolute` position to your divs for this.

Heights are variable in the example given below. and you can add any number of divs but need to define style for each one of them.

Check live example ***[here](http://cssdeck.com/labs/0merelm3)***.

Comment: It's not possible for me to get the height of one div, thus I wouldn't be able to correctly position 3, 4 or 5 (much less the correct order).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a correct answer to my question, but a workaround I did to solve it:

There are Javascript solutions to this, like [Wookmark](http://www.wookmark.com/jquery-plugin) and [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/). I used the later and it does exactly what I wanted with minimum configuration.

I'm still interested in a pure CSS solution (and surprised this is not somewhat easy to do with CSS), so I guess I'll leave this question open.